# Wikipedia in ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I want to integrate wikipedia in my iOS App (is it related to the mediawiki ?)

If so, I would like to know how I would tell wikipedia to give me an article about the `o2 arena london` (it is a one venue of London city) for example.

What would the url be for this example ?

I have searched in google and i have found this URL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=o2%20arena%20london&rvprop=content&format=json&rvsection=0&rvparse=1

But this is not providing any data.

Is there any other URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia runs on MediaWiki (plus some customizations which are also available), so the answer to your first question is "Yes".

First you need to use the [OpenSearch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aOpensearch) to find which pages contain the information you want.  Searching for `o2 arena london` is the following URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=o2+arena+london&format=jsonfm

which gives the following results:

```
[
    "o2 arena london",
    [
        "O2 Arena London"
    ]
]
```

Using these results we can ask Wikipedia to return the HTML of the page.  Here, the page "O2 Arena London" is a redirect to "O2 Arena (London)", so we need to ask Wikipedia to resolve the redirects and give us the final page.  This is done using [`action=parse`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aParsing_wikitext):

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&redirects=1&page=O2+Arena+London&format=jsonfm

Which gives the following (shortened) results:

```
{
    "parse": {
        "title": "The O2 Arena",
        "revid": 578231031,
        "redirects": [
            {
                "from": "O2 Arena London",
                "to": "The O2 Arena"
            }
        ],
    "text": {
        "*": "<div class=\"dablink\">This article is about the indoor arena located in
             London.  For other uses, see <a href=\"/wiki/O2_Arena_(disambiguation)\"
             title=\"O2 Arena (disambiguation)\" class=\"mw-redirect\">O2 Arena</a>.
```

...

You can display the result, but it may look weird without the CSS styling of Wikipedia.

Note, also, that if you want actual JSON, you would use `format=json` instead of `format=jsonfm`.

Comment: I want to display all information about `o2+arena` which wikipedia shows and i want to display in webView. suggested URL doesn't show anything :(

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to get the html suitable for a webView.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to parse the wikipedia `api` output, why not

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=O2+arena+london
```

You just search for the words separated by `+`.

Comment: Better to open the Associated App than in a browser.